# FancyBox: Refreshing Page on Next/Prev?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, fancybox

I have a fancybox Gallery installed on my wordpress but I'm trying to figure out how to get to refresh the page when a new image is displayed. If you take a look at this website [this website](http://blankreferrer.com/u/screenrant.com/galleries/the-amazing-spider-man-pics/) you can see that the images refresh the ads when you click the next, prev, or on an actual image.  Is it possible to add this to FancyBox?

Comment: you cannot do that with a lightbox because the lightbox will be closed if you refresh the page ... what you could do is to refresh specific sections of your page (via ajax) though. you should target the selector of such section using the `afterShow` callback like `$(sectionSelector).html(newContent)` (this is for fancybox v2.x but it means you hard-coded it into your wp theme)

Comment: @JFK so do you mean I would do something like `$('#ad-1, #ad2, #ad3').html(newContent)` to target each ad and refresh those sections?

Comment: that is an option, there are different ways but definitively not refreshing the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the latest fancybox.
If you have a look at the documentation, in the Callback tab (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) you'll see a bunch of callbacks that you can define.

For your particular problem, have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function(current, previous) {
        // current is the current content
        // previous the previous one
        // you can access the "Available options" displayed in the docs
    }
});​
```

The afterLoad callback will be called each time a content is loaded in fancybox (the actual image, next and prev images too)